# Is it Possible to set the Target of a form to an Iframe which has Src of a different domain

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to postback to a Iframe which is a different domain?

For eg:
`
Form runat="server" action="Something in Domain A"

```
Iframee src="DomainA.com" name="A"

      Form runat="Server" **action="DomainB/default.aspx" Target="A"**

      Form

Iframee
```

Form
`

I will do a postback in the  Iframe, so that the whole page doesnt get refreshed, but when I do a postback, can I set the Target of the Form to Iframe which has a source url from DomainA?

Please advice.

-Ben

Comment: Can someone answer this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set the form action to be an off-domain site. That restriction is really around for AJAX request.

Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: setting action to a offdomain site is ok, I was wondering if the result of the form post can be set to an Iframe which is in diferent domain though "Target" property.